# How do I set a source control plug in default for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs, visual-foxpro, foxpro

We recently installed Team Foundation Server 2008 and we are using it for both Visual Studio 2008 code and Visual FoxPro 9 code that we are still migrating to .Net. I had to install the TFS MSSCCI provider to get connectivity from the VFP9 IDE. That works fine, but Visual Studio now seems to get confused about which source control plug in to use and keeps reverting to the TFS MSSCCI provider instead of the "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" plugin that installed with Team Explorer. When the plug in changes, I get errors when trying to get/check in code from TFS. How can I get Visual Studio to keep the Team Explorer plug in as my default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried switching which source control pluggin VS 2008 is using to TFS? You can find the option under Tools>Options>Source Control. It does not appear to have a default setting option but it should save the value if you close VS after setting it.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the source control bindings were not converted as part of the move from VSS to TFS. Re-binding the solutions solved the problem.

So, the problem really wasn't that VS wasn't keeping my default selection. It was just changing the source control plug-in based on the bindings on the solution file that I was trying to open.

Answer (score 1):

From VS2008 Tools menu:
VS2008->Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection -> Choose the plug-in you want.

Answer (score 1):

@smaclell, @Vivek - Yes, I've tried that and it works for the current session, but the next time I open visual studio it reverts back.

I also saw a post that suggested that I change it to None, then close VS, then change it to TFS and close VS. That seemed to cause the default to stick on None, but when I tried to open a solution from TFS, it actually reverted to using the MSSCCI provider again.

I'm going to try doing a repair on the Team Explorer install. I think that I installed the MSSCCI provider after the Team Explorer install and maybe the sequence hosed things up.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just had the same answer, and think I solved it. You have to change it as Administrator.

So, I right-click started VS2013 as admin, set SCC plug-in to None, exited.
Then started in same way, changed to AnkhSVN, exited.

When started as normal, now have correct SVN default, not TFS!

Comment: Thanks!  That just worked for me with VS 2013 in switching to "Git Source Control Provider" from "Microsoft Git Provider".